# Add Text beneath Image background

Tags: react-native, text

I am trying to do something like this, to put a Text beneath the imagebackground in react native. It does not show up, for some reason, i do not know what and why its behaving so,hence i decided to come and ask on here.

My Code is looking something like this

As you can see, it has it, and it does not show up on the app.
Please How do I go about something like this.

Comment: I think that maybe you forgot to put your code in the question haha

Comment: @AndersonVanzo, i got it solved hence i removed it.